# How to use the iterating variable after a foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, scope, valuetuple, deconstructor

```cs
foreach (var (counter, _, _) in Count())
{
    ... // do stuff with counter
}
return counter;
```

`counter`'s out of scope after the `foreach` so the above doesn't work.

How can I use one of the iteration variables after a loop other than

```cs
int latestCounter;
foreach (var (counter, _, _) in Count())
{
    ... // do stuff with counter
    latestCounter = counter;
}
return latestCounter;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Since `Count()` works in the `foreach` loop it must be returning an `IEnumerable<>` type. Why not just use `Last()` from `System.Linq` instead and do `return Count().Select(_ => _.Item1).Last();`?

Comment: And this is an example of the XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari that iterates twice

Comment: Unless there is code that you didn't show then no, this completely removes the need for a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ok now that it's updated. Why not just do it in the loop? That's the whole point of the loop.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari how can I know when I'm at the last item inside of the loop?

Comment: This depends on what `Count()` returns. If it's an array or a list you can just store `Count()` result in a variable (ex `var values = Count()`) and then you can do `var lastValue = values[values.Count - 1]` if it's a  `List` and if I recall correctly `var lastValue = values[values.Length - 1]` for arrays. If you are concerned about doing 2 iterations just make sure you return a type that doesn't need a second iteration.

Comment: But in any case what you have will work for what you are trying to do. `latestCounter` will have the latest value and you can process `counter` within the `foreach` loop.

Comment: If use while to replace foreach  , and it can find out what is last, would you care about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Call MoveNext() until last

```
    List<int> Count = new List<int>();
    IEnumerator<int> e = Count.GetEnumerator();
    if (e.MoveNext())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var current = e.Current;
            bool anyNext = e.MoveNext();
            if (!anyNext)
            {
                // here in last
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much where the question started: (effectively) a `foreach` loop that on each iteration assigns the iteration variable to a variable defined in a containing scope.

Comment: Regarding the edit, `Current` is undefined until `MoveNext()` is called.  Also, if `Count` is empty then you'll never `break` out of the `while(true)`.  I think you'll have to start with `if (e.MoveNext())` like the previous revision to solve both problems.

Comment: ok I edited my answer @LanceU.Matthews